# Cordova camera crashes the app on android

Tags: android, cordova, camera, phonegap-plugins, phonegap-build

I'm developing application with cordova & angularjs where user is able to take photos using the official https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-camera

Camera keeps crashing kind of randomly. With my Sony Xperia z2 I haven't got i crashing, but on any other devices like SGS5 Active or older Android phones it keeps crashing after a few photos.

Camera settings:

```
  {
         sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
         correctOrientation: true,
         quality: 90,
         allowEdit: false,
         targetWidth: 1200,
         destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
         encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
         saveToPhotoAlbum: false
     }
```

What I tried to prevent crashing is this:

```
$scope.removePhotoFromDeviceMemory = function (uriToPhoto) {
        $scope.filesystemImageSuccess = function (fileEntry) {
            console.log("REMOVING POHOT FROM DEVICE")
            console.log(fileEntry);
            function removeSuccesful() {
                console.log("IMAGE REMOVED");
            }

            function removingFailed() {
                console.log("IMAGE REMOVING FAILED");

            }

            fileEntry.remove(removeSuccesful, removingFailed);
        }
        $scope.filesystemImageFail = function () {
            console.log("fuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuuu");
        }
        window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(uriToPhoto, $scope.filesystemImageSuccess, $scope.filesystemImageFail)
    }
```

So app deletes all taken photos from phone instantly after the photo is sent to backend.

So I'm currently using the FILE_URI to prevent crashings DATA_URI has, but on older devices it crashes still when user has taken ~20-40 photos.

Running out of ideas here. Any help highly appreciated!

From ADB:

> D/SystemWebViewEngine(24879): CordovaWebView is running on device made by: Sony
>   D/StatusBar.NetworkController( 1039): refreshViews: Data not connected!! Set no data type icon / Roaming
>   I/WhatsApp(24841): LL_I W [1:main]Runtime.java:421 16:25:09.343 os_core_unix.c !pjlib 2.2.1 for POSIX initialized
>   I/WhatsApp(24841): LL_I W [1:main]Runtime.java:421 16:25:09.362 wa_audio_dev.c !WA Audio sound library initialized
>   I/WhatsApp(24841): LL_I W [1:main]Runtime.java:421 16:25:09.363          pjlib  select() I/O Queue created (0x608d07b4)
>   I/WhatsApp(24841): LL_I W [1:main]Runtime.java:421 16:25:09.364      wa_opus.c  pjmedia_codec_opus_init start
>   I/WhatsApp(24841): LL_I W [1:main]Runtime.java:421 16:25:09.365      wa_opus.c  pjmedia_codec_opus_init success
>   I/dalvikvm(24879): Could not find method android.content.Context.getExternalMediaDirs, referenced from method org.apache.cordova.file.LocalFilesystem.isPublicDirectory
>   W/dalvikvm(24879): VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 59: Landroid/content/Context;.getExternalMediaDirs ()[Ljava/io/File;
>   D/dalvikvm(24879): VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x000b
>   D/dalvikvm(24841): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.whatsapp-1/libcurve25519.so 0x419cc9d8
>   I/WhatsAppJni(24841): EnsureThreadAttached: attached current thread to JVM
>   D/dalvikvm(24841): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.whatsapp-1/libcurve25519.so 0x419cc9d8
>   D/dalvikvm(24841): No JNI_OnLoad found in /data/app-lib/com.whatsapp-1/libcurve25519.so 0x419cc9d8, skipping init
>   I/WhatsApp(24841): LL_I W [1:main]WhatsAppLibLoader.java:25 native library usability testing in progress
>   I/WhatsApp(24841): LL_I W [1:main]WhatsAppLibLoader.java:25 native library usability testing complete
>   I/WhatsApp(24841): LL_I W [1:main]WhatsAppLibLoader.java:4 jniVersion: 2.12.250
>   I/WhatsApp(24841): LL_I W [1:main]WhatsAppLibLoader.java:22 isLibraryUsable: True
>   D/dalvikvm(24770): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/com.facebook.orca-1/lib/libsslx.so 0x419cff50
>   D/dalvikvm(24770): No JNI_OnLoad found in /mnt/asec/com.facebook.orca-1/lib/libsslx.so 0x419cff50, skipping init
>   D/dalvikvm(24770): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.facebook.orca-1/lib/libglog.so 0x419cff50
>   D/CordovaInterfaceImpl(24879): Sending activity result to plugin
>   D/dalvikvm(24770): Added shared lib /mnt/asec/com.facebook.orca-1/lib/libglog.so 0x419cff50
>   D/dalvikvm(24770): No JNI_OnLoad found in /mnt/asec/com.facebook.orca-1/lib/libglog.so 0x419cff50, skipping init
>   D/AndroidRuntime(24879): Shutting down VM
>   W/dalvikvm(24879): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41695d88)
>   D/dalvikvm(24770): Trying to load lib /mnt/asec/com.facebook.orca-1/lib/libdouble-conversion.so 0x419cff50
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879): Process: com.conexbird, PID: 24879
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.conexbird/com.conexbird.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=34, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.conexbird/com.conexbird.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2896)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2925)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2306)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:144)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1246)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5212)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:602)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=34, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.conexbird/com.conexbird.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3515)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2883)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        ... 12 more
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.processResultFromCamera(CameraLauncher.java:445)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at org.apache.cordova.camera.CameraLauncher.onActivityResult(CameraLauncher.java:674)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaInterfaceImpl.onActivityResult(CordovaInterfaceImpl.java:120)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at org.apache.cordova.CordovaActivity.onActivityResult(CordovaActivity.java:353)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5432)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3511)
>   E/AndroidRuntime(24879):        ... 13 more
>   W/ActivityManager(  950):   Force finishing activity com.conexbird/.MainActivity

And after that after a few lines:

> I/WindowManager(  950): Screenshot max retries 4 of Token{41a57c78
>   ActivityRecord{425a4218 u0 com.conexbird/.MainActivity t46 f}}
>   appWin=Window{426ac660 u0 Starting com.conexbird} drawState=4
>   W/WindowManager(  950): Screenshot failure taking screenshot for
>   (960x540) to layer 21020

Which I thought is quite weird too.

Comment: Any updates on that since then? I experience similar crashing on Android with plugin version 2.1.0 ...